# Restrict Google Firebase access to specific HTTP referrers

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have an API key specifically for Firebase and I have it restricted like so:
[image]

However, when I connect to Firebase from a different website (on front-end side) it still works.
I've tried connecting Google Maps and it doesn't work (because of the wrong referrer) but Firebase works.

How can I restrict Firebase access to specific web domains?

**Note: I'm not using Firebase Auth, I'm only using Firestore as a database.**

Answer (score 0):

Double check if your domain accepts HTTP and HTTPS because both require separate restrictions. Also, try adding restriction that includes a wildcard path.

Here's an example:

```
https://www.test-domain.com
https://www.test-domain.com/*

http://www.test-domain.com
http://www.test-domain.com/*
```

---

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#adding_http_restrictions

Comment: The problem is not that it doesn't work after adding the restriction but that it works even with the restriction.

In other words, there is no security at all, I can make the HTTP referrer `google.com` and I would still be able to access and use firebase through my domain.

Comment: It's been a week and if you're still not getting the answers you need, I suggest contacting Firebase support https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact

Comment: @butaminas did you ever find a solution for this? I am in the exact same scenario with non-authenticated public read/write but need to restrict it to only 1 domain to avoid bad actors!

Comment: @4ndy Yes, I've actually did what Donnald Cucharo suggested and contacted Firebase Support.

It turns out, there is no way to restrict Firestore in any other way than using Firestore rules.
In other words, you should use Firebase Authentication somewhere in your system and verify that the user is logged in using Firebase Authentication before allowing any reads / writes on your Firestore database.

FYI this wasn't what I wanted so I decided to dump Firestore all together.